# How to apply ripple effect on click and then open popup using colorbox?

Tags: jquery, colorbox, ripple

I am using colorbox plugin for lightbox, and http://db2k.github.io/MaterialRipple/ for ripple effect.
I need the effect used on https://design.google.com.

First, ripple effect will shown and then popup video open on single click on element.
I have tried with many options, settimeout and delay, but not works.

my js code is:

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".youtubevideo").colorbox({
                fastIframe:false, preloading: true, fixed: true, iframe: true, title: false, innerWidth: "100%", innerHeight: "100%", speed: 600,
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: There is a section in the jquery.materialripple.js file for removing the animated elemented. Can you not put the code that calls the colorbox into that section of the materialripple JS?

Comment: Thanks for reply. yes, may be but i need to delay colorbox open, so that ripple effect first clearly taken place, and then lightbox open. In current situation both effect (ripple and popup) applied at same time. and i am beginner to jquery for write custom code.

Comment: Hey, i have solve it. Created new custom function using setTimeout and call that function with onclick event in div. and used href: parameter for video link.